# Alert view with selectable items in iPhone monotouch

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xamarin.ios, uialertview

In the android we can have an alert dialog with a list of items like below image:

[image]

but for in iPhone case how can we create a an alert view like this?

Comment: USe UIActionSheet .....

Comment: Yes, UIActionSheet is good option but my designer prefer an alertview like above. so is there any mechanism for creating such alertviews?

Comment: For "like this" you need custom UIViewController which you will show by presentModalViewController:animated:

Comment: https://github.com/gpambrozio/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets . Try with it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need create MyCustomAlertViewController with agent name and phone properties. Create xib . After that write like this:

```
- (void) alertForAgentName: (NSString*) anAgentName agentPhoneNumber: (NSString*) anAgentPhoneNumber
{
    MyCustomAlertViewController* modalViewController =
        [[MyCustomAlertViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"MyCustomAlertViewController" bundle:nil];

    modalViewController.agentName = anAgentName;
    modalViewController.agentPhoneNumber = anAgentPhoneNumber;

    UINavigationController *modalViewNavController =
        [[UINavigationController alloc]
        initWithRootViewController: modalViewController];

    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:
        modalViewNavController animated:YES];
    // If MRC
    [modalViewNavController release];
}
```

for dismiss dialog you need call like this (it is inside of the MyCustomAlertViewController class):

```
- (IBAction) dismissModalView:(id)sender
{
    [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a alert like this

```
UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
UILabel *labelone = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
labelone.text=@"label1";
[labelone setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[labelone setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];

UILabel *labeltwo = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
labeltwo.text=@"label2";
[labeltwo setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[labeltwo setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];

UILabel *labelthree = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
labelthree.text=@"label3";
[labelthree setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[labelthree setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];

[alert addSubview:labelone];
[alert addSubview:labeltwo];
[alert addSubview:labelthree];

[alert setDelegate:self];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

If you want to adjust the framesize of the alertview you can use

```
- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView {
alertView.frame = CGRectMake(20.f, 200.f, 280.f, 150.f);
NSArray *subViewArray = alertView.subviews;
for(int x=0;x<[subViewArray count];x++){
    if([[[subViewArray objectAtIndex:x] class] isSubclassOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    {
        UILabel *label = [subViewArray objectAtIndex:x];
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    }
}
```

}